# Why does the || (or) and && (and) operator in JavaScript behave differently than in C (returning non boolean value)?

Tags: javascript, c, logical-or, logical-and

Consider the following code.

```js
console.log("All" && 1); // 1
console.log("All" || 1); // "All"
```

As you can see, the first expression, `"All" && 1`, evaluates to `1`. Which is surely not a boolean value (not a `true`). I expected here more specifically true. Because I didn't force result as `String`.

The second expression, `"All" || 1`, to evaluate to `All`. Which is also not a boolean value.

In C language, the both expression evaluates to `1`. As I force the result to convert in string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", "All" && 1); // 1
    printf("%d\n", "All" || 1); // 1
    return 0;
}
```

Why does JavaScript behave differently? More specifically Why JS returning a non boolean value?

Answer (score 9):

The logical operators in C always evaluate to boolean values. In C, the int `1` represents `true` and the int `0` represents `false`. That's the reason why both the expressions, `"All" && 1` and `"All" || 1`, evaluate to `1`. Both of them are logically true. For clarification, consider the following program.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", 20 && 10); // 1
    printf("%d\n", 20 || 10); // 1
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, the expressions `20 && 10` and `20 || 10` still evaluate to `1` even though there is no `1` in those expressions. This makes sense because both those expressions are logically true. Hence, they evaluate to `1` which is equivalent to `true` in JavaScript.

If JavaScript behaved the way C did then the expressions `"All" && 10` and `"All" || 10` would evaluate to the boolean value `true`. However, that's not the way the logical operators behave in JavaScript. That's not to say that they are buggy.

Values in JavaScript have a notion of truthiness and falsity. For example, the values `true`, `"All"`, `10`, `[10, 20]`, `{ foo: 10 }`, and `x => 2 * x` are all truthy. On the other hand, the values `false`, `""`, `0`, `undefined`, and `null` are falsy.

The logical operators of JavaScript don't always evaluate to boolean values like C does. Instead, they evaluate to one of their operands. The `&&` operator evaluates to its left operand if it's falsy. Otherwise, it evaluates to the right operand. Similarly, the `||` operator evaluates to its left operand if it's truthy. Otherwise, it evaluates to the right operand.

Now, the value `"All"` is truthy. Hence, `"All" && 1` evaluates to the right operand (i.e. `1`) whereas `"All" || 1` evaluates to the left operand (i.e. `"All"`). Notice that both `1` and `"All"` are truthy values, which means that they are equivalent to `1` (which represents truthiness) in C.

Hence, no. JavaScript is not buggy.

Answer (score -6):

I quote here from official doc :- [Logical AND in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)

> The logical AND (&&) operator (logical conjunction) for a set of operands is true if and only if all of its operands are true. It is typically used with Boolean (logical) values. When it is, it returns a Boolean value. **However, the && operator actually returns the value of one of the specified operands, so if this operator is used with non-Boolean values, it will return a non-Boolean value.**

Let's take some examples,

```
let a = [1,2,3];
console.log( 0 && a.b ); // return 0
console.log( 1 && a.b ); // return a type error.
```

In first console.log when JavaScript see `0` at first, JS interpreter stop and return first value.

This is happening because when JS interpreter translate first value to boolean, it evaluated to `false`. We know the fact that "**on any `&&` operator if a single value is `false`, it will return `false`.**

So JS interpreter here try to save some computation power by returning before, without full statement evaluation. Which is great.

The same is truth for **LOGICAL OR (||)** operator.